# IntelliJ IDEA reload file from disk on type

Tags: intellij-idea

I have used Emacs a lot, and in Emacs when you try to edit a file which has been modified on disk, it disallows it, prompts that the file has changed, and asks you what you want to do about it.

In IntelliJ, if a file has changed on disk, I can type forever. This just happened to me: I wrote a 20 line function, and tried to save. Then IntelliJ prompted that the file had changed. I had the option of overriding my changes with the data on disk, or to corrupt the whole file by keeping the current data. I wanted to just copy my function and reload, but I couldn't even do that because the popup had the focus. I there isn't even a button to cancel the save. I pressed Escape and prayed that my change would be overwritten. What a nightmare...

Is there any way to make IntelliJ prompt on the first character typed? I really don't want to synchronize the whole project every time I start to edit a file a switch git branch.

Comment: IntelliJ should be actively watching the filesystem and loading external changes immediately as they occur, before you type a single character. What OS are you using?

Comment: By the way, it's pretty much impossible to lose work in IntelliJ - you can use "local history" to get back to any previous state.

Comment: The dialog actually gives you three options, one of which shows you a merge dialog allowing you to combine the in-memory and on-disk changes.

Comment: @ChrisMartin using OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings

Under the heading 'Synchronization', enable the property 'Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation'.